# Wrong projection of raster using R

Tags: raster, r

I have a raster layer with the following structure:

```
ncols 4320
nrows 2160
xllcorner -180.0
yllcorner -90.0
cellsize 0.0833333
NODATA_value -9999.0
-9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0
```

If I then try to read it and project, it does not appear:

```
library(raster)
library(tmap)

r <- raster("baseline/baseline/zip/1870AD_pop/popc_1870AD.asc")
crs(r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" 

tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(r)+tm_raster("red")
```

For some reason, I'm unable to display it properly, even with the added crs.

`plot(r)` does give me an expected output:

[image: plot]

However, when trying to plot it on another map, it fails to do it correctly.

`summary(r)` gives the following output:

```
> summary(r)
         popc_1870AD
Min.    0.000000e+00
1st Qu. 0.000000e+00
Median  7.089942e+00
3rd Qu. 1.621315e+02
Max.    1.331152e+05
NA's    7.092085e+06
Warnmeldung:
In .local(object, ...) :
  summary is an estimate based on a sample of 1e+05 cells (1.07% of all cells)
```

The file can be downloaded here:
http://www.filedropper.com/popc1870ad

Comment: What does `summary(r)` say about it in terms of its extent?

Comment: Does a simple `plot(r)` show anything meaningful? Are you sure its not all -9999 missing data?

Comment: please see the eddits

Comment: I think I meant you to show `print(r)` which gives the full details of the geometry, but I can see from the plot that the extents etc are correct. Can you edit and add the version number of `tmap`? What do you get with your `tmap` code? Just a blank web page? Tried `tm_shape(r) + tm_raster()` (ie without the "red") to map the data?

Comment: The tmap version is 3.3-1. without the red, a legend occurs, but the data doesn't seem to be projected at the correct scale. The issue also occurs when I try to import it in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Can you share the data file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data goes up/down to 90N/S. On a Mercator projection, like on most web mapping software, this goes to +Infinity/-Infinity.

`tmap` seems to have even tighter limits on what it can display. If I crop to +/-50 I can see your data within that latitude band:

```
> rc50 = crop(r,extent(c(-180,180,-50,50)))
> tm_shape(rc50) + tm_raster()
```

[image]

but if I change it to -51 and 51, I see nothing!

If you reproject the data to the web mercator projection, then you can display more, but you still have to crop it first because otherwise you go off to infinity:

```
> rc = crop(r,extent(c(-180,180,-80,85)))
> rp = projectRaster(rc, crs="+init=epsg:3857")
```

[image]

It doesn't matter if you set the CRS like you do or not, since you are using the default CRS anyway (but its a Good Thing to set it anyway).